# Next.js: failed to render when using headers() to do api fetching

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

This is a Next.js server component using app router, and I tried to take url to do api fetching.
 Below is my code

```js
async function getPhotos() {
  const headersList = headers();
  const fullUrl = headersList.get("referer");
  const folder = fullUrl?.split("/")[4];
  const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/photo/${folder}`);
  if (!result.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return result.json();
}
const page = async () => {
  const data = await getPhotos();
  return (
    <div>
      {data && <div>show data</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The page won't render the 'show data' div after fetching the data, but if I change the `getPhotos()` function into this

```js
async function getPhotos() {
  const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/photo/folder`);
  if (!result.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return result.json();
}
```

Then the page would normally render the div.
Does anyone know why using `headers()` to fetch will cause this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: In my app, headersList.get("referer"); returns sometimes undefined, i guess that is the reason, could you have a look? maybe using a console.log?